# C Scanf in a loop

Tags: c

It works for the first time, when execute on 2nd time, it skip the second scanf function. After google from several pages, noticed that it was the behavior of the scanf function that add \n in the buffered, to solved this, I added fflush(stdin) after the scanf and it did worked, however when executed on 2nd times, it give me a wrong result. Someone can guide me what is the problem of this program ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char UserInput[50];
int i = 0;
int exit;


do{


printf("Please enter a string (less than 50 character): ");
scanf("%[a-z,A-Z, ,]s",&UserInput);

while(UserInput[i] != '\0' && i<50)
{
    i++;
}

if (i==50)
    printf("The string is too long\n");
else
    printf("The length of the string is %d\n",i);

printf("To continue, please key in any numbers other than 0: ");
scanf("%d",&exit);
    fflush(stdin);
}while(exit !=0);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Checking the length _after_ you read the input is pretty much useless. You can however tell `scanf` to get at most a specific number of character with a format such as `"%50s"`.

Comment: Read what `scanf` return value means, and check it for parse error... There's not much point in trying to figure out what's wrong with any code using `scanf` until you've ruled out the simple possibility of invalid input (or invalid format string, depending on your point of view).

Answer (score 1):

You don't use ampersand to read an array. Change the line to:

```
scanf("%[a-z,A-Z, ,]s",UserInput);
```

Also exit is also a char array, not an integer. Either change exit to be int or change the scanf to: `scanf("%s",exit);`. And trust me exit [is not a good name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) for a variable in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

Your loop to compute the length is a bit pointless, and it also doesn't reset `i` after having run once, so it'll break on the second attempt.

Remove the loop, use `strlen()` instead if you feel you must compute the length.

Even better, remove the use of `sscanf()` and use `fgets()` instead.

Note that `&UserInput` is a bit pointless, the name `UserInput` will "decay" to a pointer to the first element (`&UserInput[0]`) in a function call and is the best way to state it:

```
fgets(UserInput, sizeof UserInput, stdin);
```

is how I would write it. Don't forget to check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes and remarks :

1. when using a scanset format (`%[a-zA-Z ]`), you are not supposed to use an `s` at the end like you do, nor are the comma's supposed to be there.
2. you should check the return code when calling `scanf` to make sure that you actually succeeded reading what was supposed to be read.
3. you have a risk of overflowing the `UserInput` buffer - it only allows for a string of length 49, but you impose no such limitation when filling the buffer.
4. you don't poperly reset `i` back to `0` after each iteration.
5. `exit` should have the type `int`, since you use the format `%d` to fill it. As pointed out elsewhere, `exit` isn't a particularly good variable name in C (there is a standard function called `exit`).
6. you use multiple `scanf` calls without properly taking care of reading any leftovers from the previous read. It's better to read input line by line (using `fgets` eg.) into a buffer, and then parse the data you need out of that buffer.
7. don't use `fflush` on an input stream (like `stdin`). It is only intended for output streams.